# i have this error while running android cardview

Tags: android

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 22 more
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: please paste the xml also

Answer (score 0):

just add this `dependencies` of `constraint-layout` in gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: why downvote?I think this is the solution.Dependency is missing

Comment: @NileshRathod i think someone intentionally down vote in your post.. keep **calm**

Comment: @Anonymous someone doing intentionally this

Comment: Yes I was about to say same.This should be the answer for the question